# How do I start the mariadb service on NixOS?

Tags: nixos, mariadb

On my NixOS 17.09 system, I've installed `mariadb`, by listing the package in my `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` and `nixos-rebuild`ing.

The binaries now seem to be present, but the mariadb database service doesn't seem to be running. **How can I start it?**

I tried

```
$ sudo systemctl start mariadb
Failed to start mariadb.service: Unit mariadb.service not found.
```

```
$ sudo systemctl start mysql
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
```

```
$ sudo mysqld start
2017-11-06 11:39:35 140359451949120 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.1.28-MariaDB) starting as process 2823 ...
2017-11-06 11:39:35 140359451949120 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/nixos.lower-test
mysqld: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")
2017-11-06 11:39:35 140359451949120 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: copied from https://superuser.com/q/1265921/363905, because [unix.SE] seems like the better place for this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NixOS option [`services.mysql.enable`](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#services.mysql.enable) works for starting either MySQL implementation (`mysql-*` or `mariadb`). Which one gets started is determined by [`services.mysql.package`](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#services.mysql.package).

So in your `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` add

```
  services.mysql.package = pkgs.mariadb;
  services.mysql.enable = true;
```

(With that, you don't even need to explicitly list `mariadb` in `environment.systemPackages`.)